# Is there ever a case in which an item not useful for research is useful for anything but selling?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I've noticed several items which are marked as useless for research. Should I just sell these right away, or is there ever a case in which one of them might be useful?

Items include broken flight computers, alien food, entertainment, stasis pods, etc.

Comment: Not completely unrelated: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87482/what-alien-bits-should-i-sell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These items have absolutely no uses beside selling them, so feel free to sell those broken flight computers and alien entertainment centers as soon as possible.

Comment: I can also confirm I've played over 200 hours, on all difficulties, and never been asked for a 'useless' item

Answer (score 4):

Selling immediately is the best solution for all of these. Think of them as supplementary income.

Note that working flight computers and power sources can be used for research/construction as well as having higher monetary value. This makes EMP cannons on your interceptors a good idea. Similarly, it's best to have fights outside UFOs and be less liberal with overwatch usage inside UFOs (in case they don't hit).

Earlier in the game, even things w/ research value like corpses and Elerium are also fair game for getting extra cash for satellites or other critical infrastructure. The only things I just about never sell are alloys and weapon fragments (useful for researching and constructing weapons/armor).