# What alien bits should I sell in XCom 2?

Tags: xcom-2

It would be nice to have an XCom 2 version of the XCom: EU question: [*What alien bits should I sell?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87482/what-alien-bits-should-i-sell).

It's not obvious which alien corpses or bits of alien tech are safe to sell on the black market. e.g. I know that Faceless Corpses are used to build Mimic Beacons, but are they used for anything else? ...If I've built all the mimic beacons I'm going to want to use, should I just sell all the rest of the Faceless Corpses I find?). After I do an autopsy/breakdown of an ADVENT Officer Corpse or Turret ADVENT Wreck, are those safe to sell? etc..

**What corpses and other inventory items are necessary to keep around, and what are safe to sell on the Black Market?**

Comment: Slightly off topic, but the weapon mods are great for selling on black market. Repeaters and hair triggers aren't that great, but the money is good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You always need 1 corpse for autopsy/breakdown. You also have a minimum number of corpses needed to unlock instant autopsy/breakdown, which means that, if you want to save research time, you will only sell corpses after the autopsy is done. An exhaustive list of other uses for corpses is:

- ADVENT Trooper: 2 for Hybrid Materials (4 on Legend), 6 for Predator Armor (12 on Legend), 2 per EXO Suit (4 on Legend), 2 per Nanoscale Vest (3 on Legend).
- ADVENT Stun Lancer: 2 per Spider Suit (3 on Legend).
- Sectoid: 2 for Advanced Psi Amp (3 on Legend), 1 per Mind Shield (2 on Legend).
- Faceless: 2 per Mimic Beacon.
- Viper: 2 for Battlefield Medicine (3 on Legend), 1 per Nanomedkit (2 on Legend).
- Berserker: 1 per Overdrive Serum (2 on Legend).
- Chryssalid: 2 per Hellweave.
- Gatekeeper: 1 for Alien Psi Amp (2 on Legend).

Comment: Are you sure it's 2 berserkers per overdrive serum on legend? I unlocked it earlier today and could have sworn it was only 1.

Comment: DefaultStategyTuning.ini says the number for Legend is 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Nice answer - I assume everything else (Alloys, Elerium Crystals, Elerium Cores, etc.) are all "keep forever"? Is there anything that is purely junk, like the alien entertainment centers or alien surgeries from Enemy Unknown?

Comment: Elerium Cores are rare and useful enough to keep forever unless you already have anything you want from the Proving Grounds. Data Caches, Datapads and Facility Leads are also things you want to keep.

Comment: Alloys are used to build and research weapons and armor. You can safely sell alloys if you already have Tier 3 weapons and armor for everyone. Elerium Crystals are used for the same thing, but you also need a small amount for psi-related research and for Power Relay upgrades.

Comment: There is nothing that is purely junk - everything you can get is useful somehow, if only for research projects - but there are some which are surplus once you've done the research.

Comment: @Breno [looks like the value isn't used, then.](http://i.imgur.com/baSUUVU.jpg) I'm running vanilla -- no mods.

Comment: You can add this mod to your answer - A mod which lists in the UI which items you can sell. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=648410303&searchtext=show

Answer (score 1):

The [Blackmarket Usage](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=648410303&searchtext=) mod displays that information in-game.